# \newcommand with a tikz matrix would not compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, matrices

I've made a \newcommand containing a matrix of nodes in tikz. The thing is that when the matrix is one column only, everything works fine. When it's two columns or more it stops compiling. I am feeling stupid, where is my mistake? Here is the listing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\tikzset{tabmatrix/.style = {matrix of  nodes, 
                             nodes in empty cells, 
                             row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
                             column sep=-\pgflinewidth}}


\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
$\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]\footnotesize
\matrix [tabmatrix,nodes={draw}]
{
a & b \\ %deleting "& b" and "& d" makes everything work
c & d \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}$
}


\begin{document}
Bla bla bla \mycommand


\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ can't make `&` active when you store it in a macro. Use [`ampersand replacement`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#tikz/ampersand:replacement) or replace the `&` directly with `\pgfmatrixnextcell`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel omg this was not obvious at all, thank you so much